# caret preProcess knnImpute error more nearest neighbours than there are points

Tags: r, data-imputation, caret, data-preprocessing

I am trying to impute missing data using preProcess function in caret with kNNImpute method.

```
library(missForest)
data(iris)
## Introduce large missing values to the iris data set
set.seed(752)
iris.mis = iris
iris.mis[, c(1,3)] <- prodNA(iris[, c(1,3)], 0.95)
summary(iris.mis)

myK = min(unlist(lapply(iris.mis, function(x){150-sum(is.na(x))}))) - 1

preProcValues <- preProcess(iris.mis[, -4], method = c("knnImpute"), k = myK)
t_imp <- predict(preProcValues, iris.mis[, -4])
```

However, I got the error:

> Error in RANN::nn2(old[, non_missing_cols, drop = FALSE], new[, non_missing_cols,  : 
>     Cannot find more nearest neighbours than there are points

Is this method not suitable for large missing data?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you run into is that `knnImpute` requires at least as many samples in your data *without missing values* as you have specified with the `k` parameter for the k-nearest-neighbours. As you use `prodNA`, you distribute `NA` randomly - which with a `noNA=0.95` being pretty high, just very likely turns out to not have sufficient samples without `NA` values for your `k`:

```
table(apply(iris.mis, 1, function(r) all(!(is.na(r)))))
# FALSE 
#   150
```

What would work:

```
# slightly reduce amount of NA
iris.mis[, c(1,3)] <- prodNA(iris[, c(1,3)], 0.8)
table(apply(iris.mis, 1, function(r) all(!(is.na(r)))))
# FALSE  TRUE 
#   147     3 

# use at max the amount of samples without NA as k
myK = sum(apply(iris.mis, 1, function(r) all(!is.na(r))))

# impute as done in the question
preProcValues <- preProcess(iris.mis[, -4], method = c("knnImpute"), k = myK)
t_imp <- predict(preProcValues, iris.mis[, -4])
```

So, bottom line, `knnImpute` does work with many values missing - but if you want to use it with such few samples will depend on your problem and goal.

One more thing: keep in mind that if you would (be able to) use samples for imptutation that have certain features set to `NA` themselves this boils down to looking at samples in a subspace of your features. For example, in the extreme case of looking at and imputing 1 feature at a time only, you would not use *any other information* about a sample that has `NA` vaues to impute those. This would therefore not be classic imputation anymore which e.g. `knnImpute` is designed for.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. So, I need to have at least k valid samples in order to successfully run knnimpute? Another problem is that I cannot impute categorical data. If I do change it to numeric, the imputed values are wrong i.e. they are imputed to decimal values. How can I solve this?

Comment: @user1480478 Yes, the first is correct. The second is a whole new question on its own - you are probably better searching for it separately/asking a new question for it. But in short: yes, you could impute categorial features too (think e.g. of a majority vote of $k$ neighbours for the value to use). But I don't know by heart if `knnImpute` is capable of doing this.